# tailwind: responsive design not working on grid

Tags: css, grid, tailwind-css

I wanted to turn `grid-cols-4` to `grid-cols-1` on smaller screen sizes. The below code does not solve the issue. It stays at `grid-cols-1` itself:

```
      <div className="grid grid-cols-1 md:grid-cols-4 gap-4 ">
        <div className='images col-span-2'>...</div>
        <div className='info col-span-2'>...</div>
      </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it by uninstalling tailwind and installing it again but this time did this:

`npx tailwindcss -i ./src/input.css -o ./src/output.css --full`

Added the `--full` option to it.